# How Can I Convert 2 list of data in html table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binance, cryptocurrency

I was Trying To Get All Of My Future Open Position at Binance in Python This is my code-

```
from binance.client import Client
client = Client("api key", "secret key")
import pandas as pd
import html

pos_info = client.futures_position_information()

for b in pos_info:
    if float(b['positionAmt']) > 0:
        print(b)
```

and i get this as output

```
{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'positionAmt': '0.283', 'entryPrice': '3520.15', 'markPrice': '3473.53457777', 'unRealizedProfit': '-13.19216449', 'liquidationPrice': '3184.27536722', 'leverage': '10', 'maxNotionalValue': '4000000', 'marginType': 'isolated', 'isolatedMargin': '86.36610623', 'isAutoAddMargin': 'false', 'positionSide': 'BOTH', 'notional': '983.01028550', 'isolatedWallet': '99.55827072', 'updateTime': 1648860967577}
{'symbol': 'SANDUSDT', 'positionAmt': '274', 'entryPrice': '3.642445620438', 'markPrice': '3.63380000', 'unRealizedProfit': '-2.36889988', 'liquidationPrice': '3.31094684', 'leverage': '10', 'maxNotionalValue': '250000', 'marginType': 'isolated', 'isolatedMargin': '97.53375892', 'isAutoAddMargin': 'false', 'positionSide': 'BOTH', 'notional': '995.66120000', 'isolatedWallet': '99.90265880', 'updateTime': 1648864488900}
```

***Now How Can I Get These Value In Html Table***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Pandas function [`to_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html).

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([b for b in pos_info if float(b['positionAmt']) > 0])
df.to_html('output.html', index=False)
```

Output table:

| symbol | positionAmt | entryPrice | markPrice | unRealizedProfit | liquidationPrice | leverage | maxNotionalValue | marginType | isolatedMargin | isAutoAddMargin | positionSide | notional | isolatedWallet | updateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ETHUSDT | 0.283 | 3520.15 | 3473.53457777 | -13.19216449 | 3184.27536722 | 10 | 4000000 | isolated | 86.36610623 | false | BOTH | 983.01028550 | 99.55827072 | 1648860967577 |
| SANDUSDT | 274 | 3.642445620438 | 3.63380000 | -2.36889988 | 3.31094684 | 10 | 250000 | isolated | 97.53375892 | false | BOTH | 995.66120000 | 99.90265880 | 1648864488900 |

Answer (score 0):

```
a = pd.DataFrame()
for b in pos_info:
    if float(b['positionAmt']) > 0:
        a.append(b, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: I added a DataFrame before the for loop in which you could add b as row to the DataFrame

Comment: Just for reference append was [deprecated in 1.4.0 and will be removed in a future version](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#deprecated-dataframe-append-and-series-append)